# How to toggle CSS class based on a value in a Svelte store

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte, store

I am new to Svelte and I am struggling with the stores. What I am trying is to individually toggle the background color of an element in an each loop. I figured it out by simply giving each div block its own html id and then addressing it via getElementById().

My question is, is there a more elegant way to do it?

Like binding the individual css classes of each div-block to the store values? I tried thing like class:backgound={todo.done} but that only worked on the initial render. Once the value was updated, it didn't work.

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

 export const list = writable([
        {
        text: 'test1',
        done: false,
        id:1,
         },
          {
        text: 'test2',
        done: true,
        id:2,
         },
           {
        text: 'test3',
        done: false,
        id:3,
         },

    ]);
```

There seems to be something I am missing when it comes to how and when the store is accessed. What I want to avoid is to store the props in a variable because I never know how many elements there will be in the store.

```
<script>
        import {list} from './stores.js'
  
        const toggleDone = (todo) => {
            todo.done = !todo.done
            let elem = document.getElementById(todo.id);
            elem.style.backgroundColor = todo.done ? 'red' : '';
            console.log($list)
        }
   
        let completedTodos = $list.filter((todo) => todo.completed).length
        let totalTodos = $list.length
</script>

<style>
    .list {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        padding-right: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        
    }
    .active {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<h2 id="">{completedTodos} out of {totalTodos} items completed</h2>

{#each $list as todo, index (todo.id)}
    <div class="list" id="{todo.id}"  >
    <form action="">
        <input type="checkbox" checked={todo.done} on:click={toggleDone(todo)}>
    </form>
    {todo.text} id: {todo.id}
    </div>
{/each}
```

Comment: When you click on your checkbox, did your function `toggleDone` is called? (Do you see your log in console?)

Comment: Yes it is. Every time it calls console.log($list ) with the done property correctly updated.

Comment: When you set your background color, try `elem.style.backgroundColor = (todo.done ? 'red' : '');`

Comment: Try `elem.textContent = ‘coucou’;` to see if your element is well selected (if text is displayed or not)

Comment: Also, I see you have only number in id of your elements (json), try to add characters before like `id : ‘element_1’`. dom don’t like IDs with only numbers

Comment: Just a disclaimer. The code above works as expected. I can toggle the background color. My question is if its possible to bind a css class to a value in store like:
 <div class="list" class:backgound={todo.done}"> because that way it couldn't get it to run but it would be more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a function to toggle the item, or rather that the function is fully disconnected from the store: Svelte does not know that the item in the function is a part of the store, the function also could be called with other values.

The easiest fix is to toggle the item inline:

```html
<div class="list" class:active={todo.done}>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={todo.done}
            on:click={() => todo.done = !todo.done}>
        {todo.text} id: {todo.id}
    </label>
</div>
```

Or rather, you could just use `bind:`

```html
<input type="checkbox" bind:checked={todo.done}>
```

(Also, please use `label` elements like this, so it is more accessible. Clicking the label will also toggle the item.)

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/21fca62a556447d8ac9dd8b157ae12b9?version=3.50.0)

If the function is implemented in a way that it writes to the store, state will update correctly as well. For list this usually can be done most conveniently via the index, e.g.

```js
function toggle(index) {
    $list[index].done = !$list[index].done
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked={todo.done}
       on:click={() => toggle(index)}>
```